# How to apply a function to a series with mixed numbers and integers

Tags: python, pandas, types, series

I have ICD 9 codes that are a mixture of integers and strings. I need to group the codes into categories. Codes that are strings go into one group called `'abc'` and then purely numerical codes are grouped based on the range of values that the code falls into. I have tried lots of methods and am not having any luck, here are a couple below.

```
a=pd.Series(['v2',2,7,22,'v4'])
print (a.dtype)
a=a.apply(lambda x: 'abc' if x[0]=='v' else x)
a=a.apply(lambda x: 'def' if x>=1 and x<10 else x)
a=a.apply(lambda x: 'ghi' if x>=10 and x<30 else x)
```

This gives me the error message:

```
'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I have also tried:

```
a=pd.Series(['v2',2,7,22,'v4'])
print (a.dtype)
a=a.apply(lambda x: 'abc' if x.astype(str).str[0]=='v' else x)
a=a.apply(lambda x: 'def' if x.astype(int)>=1 and x.astype(int)<10 else x)
a=a.apply(lambda x: 'ghi' if x.astype(int)>=10 and x.astype(int)<30 else x)
```

And got the error message:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'as type'
```

Thank you for your help. I need to use pandas because this is part of a bigger data frame. There is the added complication that I have some codes that begin with 'e' and some with 'v' and they need to go into different categories. Despite this, when I use to_numeric with my data frame it is not converting the numerical elements in the column to a numerical datatype. (the code below refers to my actual data, where diag_1 etc refers to the column name and diabetic_data is the data frame.

```
    list_diag=['diag_1','diag_2','diag_3']
    for i in list_diag:
    pd.to_numeric(diabetic_data[i],errors='coerce').fillna(-1)
    print(diabetic_data[i].dtype)
```

Any ideas why the datatype isn't converting? At the moment it is treating al of the elements in the column as a string, since when I tried 'is instance(x,str)', all of the column converted to 'abc' effectively.

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(diabetic_data[i],errors='coerce').fillna(-1)` - does NOT change data in place - it returns converted Series, so you should do it this way: `diabetic_data[i] = pd.to_numeric(diabetic_data[i],errors='coerce').fillna(-1)`

Answer (score 4):

I would use [pd.cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method:

```
In [15]: a
Out[15]:
0    v2
1     2
2     7
3    22
4    v4
dtype: object

In [16]: pd.cut(pd.to_numeric(a, errors='coerce').fillna(-1),
    ...:        bins=[-np.inf, -1, 9, np.inf],
    ...:        labels=['abc','def','ghi']
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[16]:
0    abc
1    def
2    def
3    ghi
4    abc
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [abc < def < ghi]
```

NOTE: this solution assumes that you don't have negative numbers in the series

**Explanation:**

first let's replace all non-numeric values with `-1`:

```
In [17]: pd.to_numeric(a, errors='coerce').fillna(-1)
Out[17]:
0    -1.0
1     2.0
2     7.0
3    22.0
4    -1.0
dtype: float64
```

now we can categorize bins using `pd.cut()`:

```
In [18]: pd.cut(pd.to_numeric(a, errors='coerce').fillna(-1),
    ...:        bins=[-np.inf, -1, 9, np.inf],
    ...:        labels=['abc','def','ghi']
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[18]:
0    abc
1    def
2    def
3    ghi
4    abc
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [abc < def < ghi]
```

**UPDATE:** here is a more generic solution (thanks to [@Boud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785651/how-to-apply-a-function-to-a-series-with-mixed-numbers-and-integers/41786014?noredirect=1#comment70762900_41786014) for the hint!) which should work also for negative numbers

Source DF:

```
In [34]: x
Out[34]:
   val
0   v2
1  -10
2   -1
3    0
4   v5
5    9
6   10
7   13
8   22
9   v4

In [35]: x.assign(
    ...:    cat=pd.cut(pd.to_numeric(x['val'], errors='coerce').fillna(-np.inf),
    ...:        bins=[-np.inf, np.iinfo(np.int64).min, -1, np.inf],
    ...:        labels=['NaN','<0','>=0'],
    ...:        include_lowest=True))
    ...:
Out[35]:
   val  cat
0   v2  NaN
1  -10   <0
2   -1   <0
3    0  >=0
4   v5  NaN
5    9  >=0
6   10  >=0
7   13  >=0
8   22  >=0
9   v4  NaN
```

Comment: and if you deal with unknown positive and begative values, you can coerce+fillna with `-np.inf` and keep the left boundary of the cut as a bucket.

Comment: @Boud, good point, thank you! I've updated the answer correspondingly

Comment: Thank you - this is really helpful. I have added some more detail to my question because it is still not working for me.

Comment: @ags, could you provide a reproducible (similar to what you have) sample data set and desired data set?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to test the type but you're doing is with the wrong (non existing) function. Here is the way to achieve it while following your algorithm style:

```
a.apply(lambda x: 'abc' if isinstance(x, str) else
                  'def' if x>=1 and x<10 else
                  'ghi' if x>=10 and x<30 else x)
Out[31]: 
0    abc
1    def
2    def
3    ghi
4    abc
dtype: object
```

Note that I recommend MaxU approach with `pd.cut` for readability.

Answer (score 0):

not using pandas

list comprehensions selecting elements by type with isinstance()

itertools.groupby() needs a key function, I just made one up

```
a = ['v2',2,7,22,'v4', 77, 'fred']

a_strs = [e for e in a if isinstance(e, str)]

print('strings: ', a_strs)

a_ints = [e for e in a if isinstance(e, int)]

print('ints: ', a_ints)


from itertools import groupby

groups = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(a_ints, key=lambda x: x//10)]

print('group by decade ', groups)

strings:  ['v2', 'v4', 'fred']
ints:  [2, 7, 22, 77]
group by decade  [[2, 7], [22], [77]]
```